# Write to Chef::Log from a template script?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I work on a team that decided long ago to use Chef's template resource to make dynamic scripts to be executed in an execute reource block.

I know this feature was only built to generate config files and the like, but I have to work with what I've got here.

Basically I need to know how to write to `Chef::Log` from a Ruby script generated from a template block. The script is not in the same context as the cookbook that generated it, so I can't just call `require 'chef/log'` in the script. I also do not want to just append the chef-run.log because that runs into timing problems.

Is there any way to accomplish this as cleanly as possible without appending to chef-run.log?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Chef::Log` is a global, so technically you can just call its methods directly from inside a template, but this is really weird and you probably shouldn't. Do whatever logging you need from the recipe code instead. If you need to log some values, compute them in the recipe and them pass them in using `variables`.

Comment: If the templated script has `require chef/log` and calls `Chef::Log "FooBar"` if says the chef/log package is not found. I'm pretty sure this is because the script is not executed in the same context as the chef-client??

Comment: You don't need the `require`, it's a global variable. That's also not how you log in things, try `::Chef::Log.debug("foobar")`. But again, seriously don't do this it's a terrible idea.

Comment: I'll just have to settle with logging to a separate file for the template and not try logging to chef-run.log. I wish I didn't inherit this ugly code. Deadlines are deadlines and a bodge is quicker than a rewrite. :\ Thanks for the assistance @coderanger

Comment: No, the code does not work. Running `::Chef::Log.debug("foobar")` inside an .erb file raises `uninitialized constant Chef (NameError)`.

Comment: Running `::Chef::Log.debug("foobar")` from an .erb file? Could I see a sample of your code?

Comment: Yep, the template file is at the bottom of that pastebin.

Comment: This is interesting could you maybe post a sample of your template block as well? I wan't to see how that is being initialized.

Comment: Really not a whole lot to it `template '../wat' do source 'wat.erb' end`

Comment: Okay this does work. However it looks like you can only print Strings. I was looking to reference the Chef logger from inside the erb and log dynamically.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, you can only show characters on the screen so it's got to be a string at some point.

Comment: For example, the erb file loops through data and prints information that changes constantly. The method you've provided is great for data that is know upon compile-time. But this data needs to be pulled during runtime, therefore I need to be able to pass string variables to the logger.

Comment: http://hastebin.com/izarirorut.txt works just fine, whatever issue you are having is in your own code, not Chef.

Comment: This works, but it's not dynamic. You can't pass the logger Object to the script and let the script log to it... Your example is logging when the template is being generated. Even your variables are generated in compile-time. This is still not what I need.
I just don't think this is possible because Chef templates were never meant to run in the same object-space as the recipe (this is in the docs), therefore it doesn't inherit the Chef logger.

Comment: I must thank you for your help with this. I really do appreciate your time.

Comment: Again, you misunderstand how Chef and Ruby works. If you have something working then mazel tov, but for others that find this later, it's important :)